# How does PostgreSQL resolve pg_temp?

Tags: postgresql, schema, temporary-tables

`pg_temp` is an alias for current session's temporary-table schema.

> Likewise, the current session's temporary-table schema, `pg_temp_nnn`, is always searched if it exists. It can be explicitly listed in the path by using the alias `pg_temp`.
>
> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#id-1.6.7.14.2.2.2.1.4

How does PostgreSQL resolve the `pg_temp` alias to the actual temporary-table schema? Or, if that's not accessible by the user, what's the easiest way to resolve it as a user?

(NB My guess would be that PostgreSQL does not resolve it via [`pg_my_temp_schema()`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/76516/179199), because `pg_temp` [already existed in PostgreSQL 8.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SEARCH-PATH), but `pg_my_temp_schema()` [was added in PostgreSQL 8.2](https://pgpedia.info/p/pg_my_temp_schema.html).)

Answer (score 2):

`pg_my_temp_schema()` [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE), so you can use it without any worries. It just exposes an internal PostgreSQL variable to the user. This is the documentation for that variable:

```c
/*
 * myTempNamespace is InvalidOid until and unless a TEMP namespace is set up
 * in a particular backend session (this happens when a CREATE TEMP TABLE
 * command is first executed).  Thereafter it's the OID of the temp namespace.
 *
 * [...]
 */
```

PostgreSQL uses `myTempNamespace` to resolve `pg_temp`. If no temporary schema exists yet, it is ignored when looking up objects. When creating objects in `pg_temp`, the actual temporary schema is created on the fly if it does not exist yet.